# Как присвоить ширину блока в зависимости от ширины другого?

Tags: jquery, css

[image: Пример]
Имеется блок жёлтого цвета, ему нужно назначить ширину такую же как у вкладки меню. Какой корректный способ существует для этого?
Блоки находятся в разных контейнерах и разных файлах phtml. Ширина вкладки меню пляшет потому, что у конечного пользователя не всегда один и тот же шрифт.

Comment: `$('#block-acceptor').width( $('#block-donor').width() )`

Comment: Переверстать лейаут?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селекторы смените на свои. Здесь width() = длина элемента + падинги

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-item').width($('#yellow-block').width());
});
```

Comment: Благодарю! Корректно будет если я вряд напишу несколько строк $('#menu-item').width($('#yellow-block').width());, только со своими классами? Так как нужно привязать к каждой вкладке блок.

Comment: Конечно. Только Вам лучше не по классу делать привязку, а именно по  ID. Классов может быть много на странице, а ID элемента - должно быть уникальным.